How to create two Makefiles that compile two executables where one has #define and the other doesn't
I'm programming in a unix-like environment, and I currently have one C++ source file
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "This will only print in debug mode" << endl;
    #endif

    cout << "Hello!";

    return 0;
}

I also have two makefiles. One compiles the source code without the -D flag, so that only "Hello!" is printed. The other compiles the source code with the -DDEBUG flag so that the contents inside the #ifdef will run, as well as the final cout line.
release.mak
main: main.o
    g++ -o main main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -pedantic-errors -ansi -Wall -c main.cpp

debug.mak
main_debug: main.o
    g++ -o main_debug main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -DDEBUG -pedantic-errors -ansi -Wall -c main.cpp

However, when I run the command
make -f debug.mak
Then
make -f release.mak
Both executables main and main_debug print the line inside the #ifdef. I want the main file to only print "Hello!", and the main_debug file to print both the contents of the #ifdef and "Hello!"

The problem is that main.o is built by both files with different settings. Typically, you'd have a "clean" target (marked as phony), which would delete those leftovers and which you would run when switching. BTW: For complex projects, I wouldn't use plain "make" any longer, but switch to something like e.g. Bazel or cmake, which are better investments for my time.

You can have both in a single Makefile, but you have to keep all intermediate files separate:
$(shell mkdir -p obj/Release obj/Debug)

SRC = main.cpp

OBJ_DEBUG = $(SRC:%.cpp=obj/Debug/%.o)
OBJ_RELEASE = $(SRC:%.cpp=obj/Release/%.o)

CXXFLAGS = -pedantic-errors -ansi -Wall
CXXFLAGS_DEBUG = $(CXXFLAGS) -g -DDEBUG
CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = $(CXXFLAGS) -O2

obj/Debug/%.o: %.cpp
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS_DEBUG) $^ -c -o $@

obj/Release/%.o: %.cpp
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS_RELEASE) $^ -c -o $@

main_debug: $(OBJ_DEBUG)
  $(CXX) $^ -o $@

main: $(OBJ_RELEASE)
  $(CXX) $^ -o $@

Modifying the Makefile so the debug build has a -g linker flag is left as an exercise to the reader.
